# Extract part of string in Golang?

Tags: go

I'm learning Golang so I can rewrite some of my shell scripts.

I have URL's that look like this:

```
https://example-1.example.com/a/c482dfad3573acff324c/list.txt?parm1=value,parm2=value,parm3=https://example.com/a?parm1=value,parm2=value
```

I want to extract the following part:

```
https://example-1.example.com/a/c482dfad3573acff324c/list.txt
```

In a shell script I would do something like this:

```
echo "$myString" | grep -o 'http://.*.txt'
```

What is the best way to do the same thing in Golang, only by using the standard library?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few options:

```
// match regexp as in question
pat := regexp.MustCompile(`https?://.*\.txt`)
s := pat.FindString(myString)

// everything before the query 
s := strings.Split(myString, "?")[0] string

// same as previous, but avoids []string allocation
s := myString
if i := strings.IndexByte(s, '?'); i >= 0 {
    s = s[:i]
}

// parse and clear query string
u, err := url.Parse(myString)
u.RawQuery = ""
s := u.String()
```

The last option is the best because it will handle all possible corner cases.

<kbd>[try it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eNmaj2RpjC)</kbd>

Comment: I'd recommend using the url.Parse since that should handle any weird edge cases which might be missed by a regex or a split.  For example, URLs without a ?

Comment: I agree that url.Parse is the best approach. All of the options listed handle URLs without a `?`.

Answer (score 4):

you may use `strings.IndexRune`, `strings.IndexByte`, `strings.Split`, `strings.SplitAfter`,   `strings.FieldsFunc`, `url.Parse`, `regexp` or your function.

first most simple way:
you may use `i := strings.IndexRune(s, '?')` or `i := strings.IndexByte(s, '?')` then `s[:i]` like this (with commented output):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    s := `https://example-1.example.com/a/c482dfad3573acff324c/list.txt?parm1=value,parm2=value,parm3=https://example.com/a?parm1=value,parm2=value`
    i := strings.IndexByte(s, '?')
    if i != -1 {
        fmt.Println(s[:i]) // https://example-1.example.com/a/c482dfad3573acff324c/list.txt
    }
}
```

or you may use `url.Parse(s)` (I'd use this):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/url"

func main() {
    s := `https://example-1.example.com/a/c482dfad3573acff324c/list.txt?parm1=value,parm2=value,parm3=https://example.com/a?parm1=value,parm2=value`
    url, err := url.Parse(s)
    if err == nil {
        url.RawQuery = ""
        fmt.Println(url.String()) // https://example-1.example.com/a/c482dfad3573acff324c/list.txt
    }
}
```

or you may use `regexp.MustCompile(".*\\.txt")`:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

var rgx = regexp.MustCompile(`.*\.txt`)

func main() {
    s := `https://example-1.example.com/a/c482dfad3573acff324c/list.txt?parm1=value,parm2=value,parm3=https://example.com/a?parm1=value,parm2=value`

    fmt.Println(rgx.FindString(s)) // https://example-1.example.com/a/c482dfad3573acff324c/list.txt
}
```

or you may use `splits := strings.FieldsFunc(s, func(r rune) bool { return r == '?' })` then `splits[0]`:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    s := `https://example-1.example.com/a/c482dfad3573acff324c/list.txt?parm1=value,parm2=value,parm3=https://example.com/a?parm1=value,parm2=value`
    splits := strings.FieldsFunc(s, func(r rune) bool { return r == '?' })
    fmt.Println(splits[0]) // https://example-1.example.com/a/c482dfad3573acff324c/list.txt
}
```

you may use `splits := strings.Split(s, "?")` then `splits[0]`:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    s := `https://example-1.example.com/a/c482dfad3573acff324c/list.txt?parm1=value,parm2=value,parm3=https://example.com/a?parm1=value,parm2=value`
    splits := strings.Split(s, "?")
    fmt.Println(splits[0]) // https://example-1.example.com/a/c482dfad3573acff324c/list.txt
}
```

you may use `splits := strings.SplitAfter(s, ".txt")` then `splits[0]`:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    s := `https://example-1.example.com/a/c482dfad3573acff324c/list.txt?parm1=value,parm2=value,parm3=https://example.com/a?parm1=value,parm2=value`
    splits := strings.SplitAfter(s, ".txt")
    fmt.Println(splits[0]) // https://example-1.example.com/a/c482dfad3573acff324c/list.txt
}
```

or you may use your function (most independent way):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func left(s string) string {
    for i, r := range s {
        if r == '?' {
            return s[:i]
        }
    }
    return ""
}

func main() {
    s := `https://example-1.example.com/a/c482dfad3573acff324c/list.txt?parm1=value,parm2=value,parm3=https://example.com/a?parm1=value,parm2=value`
    fmt.Println(left(s)) // https://example-1.example.com/a/c482dfad3573acff324c/list.txt
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are prosessing only URLs, you can use Go's `net/url` library https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/ to parse the URL, truncate the Query and Fragment parts (Query would be `parm1=value,parm2=value` etc.), and extract the remaining portion `scheme://host/path`, as in the following example (https://play.golang.org/p/Ao0jU22NyA):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    u, _ := url.Parse("https://example-1.example.com/a/b/c/list.txt?parm1=value,parm2=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fa%3Fparm1%3Dvalue%2Cparm2%3Dvalue#somefragment")
    u.RawQuery, u.Fragment = "", ""
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", u)
}
```

Output:

```
https://example-1.example.com/a/b/c/list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I used regexp package extract string from string .

In this example I wanted to extract between  and <\PERSON> , did this by re expression and and replaced  and <\PERSON> by re1 expression.

for loop used for if there there are multiple match and re1 format used for replace.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`<PERSON>(.*?)</PERSON>`)

    string_l := "java -mx500m -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -textFile PatrickYe.txt -outputFormat inlineXML 2> /dev/null I complained to <ORGANIZATION>Microsoft</ORGANIZATION> about <PERSON>Bill Gates</PERSON>.They     told me to see the mayor of <PERSON>New York</PERSON>.,"
    x := re.FindAllString(string_l, -1)        
    fmt.Println(x)
    for v,st:= range x{
            re1 := regexp.MustCompile(`<(.?)PERSON>`)
            y1 := re1.ReplaceAllLiteralString(st,"")
            fmt.Println(v,st," : sdf : ",y1) 

    }    
}
```

[Play with Go](https://play.golang.org/p/inVaPAAMJuY)

Comment: Hi and welcome! I am sorry but it is a bit difficult to understand your question. Could you rephrase it a bit so it is easier to understand what you want to achieve?